# Style of <html:text> Struts tag

Tags: html, css, struts-1

I have to modify a code using Struts. More precisely, I have to modify the style of some HTML inputs that are coded as `<html:text>` Struts tags.

So for example, I have:

```
<html:text name="myName" property="myProperty" 
           maxlength="24" size="25" 
           onchange="JavaScript:fooBar();" />
```

The inputs are actually displayed with disabled content and I would like to modify this. (The web browser I'm working on is IE 11).

**EDIT:**

The Struts tag actually generate this HTML :

```html
<INPUT onchange=JavaScript:myFoo();myBar(this); 
       disabled="disabled" 
       maxLength=24 
       size=25
       value=myValue 
       name=myProperty>
```

So it is clear that the `disabled` attribute is the origin of the problem but I don't know what might be the cause why Struts generates it in this case.

**EDIT:**

It appears that the display is different from a version of Internet Explorer to the other, for example when using IE 10, the inputs are not disabled and the `disabled` attribute value is an empty string (i.e. `disabled=""` in the HTML tag).

Comment: What CSS is applied to this element?

Comment: @ytg I indeed explored all the css files of the project and found nothing that would disable ``<html:text>`` tags, that's why I'm wondering if the ``disabled`` property is not generated on Struts server side.

Comment: What is the raw html code that is sent to the browser? Can you see it from Wireshark or check with curl?